# play framework error

Tags: playframework, traceback

I am getting this error when I am simply trying to run play command from command prompt in windows.

```
C:\Users\naveenreddy>play
 Traceback (most recent call last):   File "E:\andrew\structure\play-1.2\play", line 13, in <module>     from play.application import PlayApplication   File "E:\andrew\structure\play-1.2\framework\pym\play\application.py", line 5,  in <module>     import socket   File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 47, in <module>     import _socket ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.  
C:\Users\naveenreddy>
```

I have set the play directory in path and have installed python already which I use to run django. What could cause this error?!

Answer (score 2):

It is most likely a conflict with python versions. Try taking python out of your path, so play can use the built in python.