# "ImportError: DLL load failed" when trying to run Play framework for the first time

Tags: python, playframework

Thinking I'd jump right into this without any issues, I was surprised that I can't even get the framework to initialize. Below is the error I am getting.

```
C:\>play
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Play\play-1.2.1\play", line 13, in <module>
    from play.application import PlayApplication
  File "C:\Play\play-1.2.1\framework\pym\play\application.py", line 5, in <module>
    import socket
  File "C:\csvn\Python25\lib\socket.py", line 45, in <module>
    import _socket
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Can anyone help me? I did find this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892060/play-framework-error), so I removed all instances of Python from my path and, as far as I can see, there's nothing there that should be getting in the way.

Thanks!

Comment: Eager to get this working, I uninstalled CollabNet Subversion and tried again. It worked. 
That said, I would like to keep this question open for the time being. The Play! framework seems to be really picking up in popularity, and since my setup is fairly normal and straightforward, I am sure others will run into this, and not everyone may be able to easily uninstall their Subversion client.

Comment: Can you raise a bug report at http://play.lighthouseapp.com?

Comment: @niels I created ticket #948 for this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C:\csvn\Python25\lib\socket.py ? Looks like you're using a preinstalled Python 2.5 instead of the bundled Python 2.6... Do you have Python-related environment settings?

Comment: I did have csvn in my path, but I removed it...and was very thorough to make sure it wasn't still there somehow. Until I uninstalled csvn (thus wiping out the preinstalled Python 2.5), the errors persisted.

Answer (score 0):

you could have just set PYTHON_HOME environment variable to point to play's python